# Новые места для QDockWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Есть QDockWidget, его можно перемещать только вверх, вниз, вправо и влево внутри QMainWindow и вокруг центрального виджета, возможно ли предопределять для него другие места? К примеру у меня есть layout с виджетами и мне хотелось бы чтобы QDockWidget можно было перетягивать внутрь этого layout'а в новые мною созданные предопределённые для него места.

Comment: Ну это вам нужно переопределить drag&drop у QDockWidget и в зависимости от координат проверять какой под курсором виджет, если это нужный вам - значит менять у QDockWidget родителя.